# (updated a lot) Computer stays running after power off

Tags: dell, power-management, shutdown, fan

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a new SSD in a *Dell Inspiron 15 5565 laptop*. There is no dual-boot configuration.

When I power off from the menu, the computer and screen appear to turn off. However, the fan still runs and the power button light stays on. The only way to actually shut it down is to hold down the power button. There are no power-related BIOS settings options aside from the "PowerNow!" AMD settings which is unrelated to the issue as far as I can tell.

Updates:

-Added exact model info

-Issue is known to not occur with the following
(Booted from hard drive) Windows 10, Manjaro, Arch, same Ubuntu version

(From USB) Manjaro, Arch, Ubuntu 20.04

.

Suggested fixes tried:

-Disabled "hibernation"/"suspend" power options via terminal

-Checked BIOS for potentially relevant power options

Comment: This is sometimes machine-specific. Could you [edit] your question to include the model of your Dell notebook as well as a little more detail regarding the solutions you've tried? It does nobody any good to suggest things you've already tried 

Comment: I have boxes that continue running the fan for atime after the OS has shutdown until the box temperature gets below a set level.  It's not the OS that does this, but the box firmware (*for longer life of the hardware you were advised to not forceably stop if as it would stop automatically after temperature threshold has been reached*)   Are you sure your box isn't just doing this too.

Comment: Do they eventually shut off or do they stay on indefinitely?

Comment: Matigo- edited to include all info you asked for. I assumed it wasn't machine issue since this was the only distro its ever happened with; but I don't know much so thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Nmath & guiverc- thank you for your inputs! No it does not shut down eventually, it will do it until the battery dies if I let it. The fan stays at a consistent low speed and does not seem to be cooling down a warm area near the latch where the output is. I cleaned the fan recently and its fine.

Comment: you can make a visual deploy by pressing "Esc" when ubuntu poweroff logo is showing... could you see that ?